# How to start / stop Licode?

Tags: licode

I don't know how to stop ,how to start the Licode server .I just know the shell script ./licode/scripts/initLicode.sh. to let the example run.

Can anyone help me to figure out how to start / stop the Licode server?

http://lynckia.com/licode/

Answer (score 1):

I just killed all node processes then reran the licode init script and the basic example script.

sudo killall node

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop all node processes and run the initLicode and initBasicExample scripts